# having troubles with making a multiple html table download using tabulator?

Tags: javascript, laravel, tabulator

i could manage rendering two tables on one page with tabulator. now i need to export both tables into one excel workbook (different sheets).

i've tried examples provided in the documentation but couldn't achieve success.

**included scripts inside head tags**

```
{{-- tabulator links --}}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/tabulator/tabulator_simple.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/tabulator/tabulator_custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="js/tabulator/tabulator.min.js"></script>

{{-- XLSX Script Includes --}}
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://oss.sheetjs.com/js-xlsx/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
```

**inside body tags i've put:**

```
<br />
<input class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="download-xlsx" value="Download Excel">
<br />

{{-- tabulator table --}}
<br> table-1 caption <br />
<div id="tableOne" style="margin-top:15px"></div>

<br> table-2 caption <br />
<div id="tableTwo" style="margin-top:15px"></div>
```

**and this is what i've inside script tags**

```
//define data
    var one = {!!$one!!}

    //define table
    var table = new Tabulator("#tableOne", {
        data:one,
        autoColumns:true,
        height:"500px",
        layout:"fitDataFill",
        selectable:true,
        clipboard:true,
    });

    //define data
    var two = {!!$two!!}

    //define table
    var table = new Tabulator("#tableTwo", {
        data:two,
        autoColumns:true,
        height:"500px",
        layout:"fitDataFill",
        // layout:"fitColumns",
        selectable:true,
        clipboard:true,
    });    

    //trigger download of data.xlsx file
    var sheets = {
    "sheetA": "#tableOne",
    "sheetB": "#tableTwo",
    };

    $("#download-xlsx").click(function(){
    table.download("xlsx", "AllData.xlsx", {sheets:sheets});
});
```

when download button is clicked, excel workbook opens up with 2 sheets. First sheet contains fist table, and that's ok. but second sheet is empty. why so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dota2pro/6m9rdo37/20/) you need to put the table variables in the sheets variable whom you want to download create an empty table0 to merge and download them

```
var sheets = {
"Example Data1": table1,
    "Example Data2": table2
};

    downloadXlxs = function(){
table0.download("xlsx", "data.xlsx", {sheets:sheets});
};
```